# Nginx Subdomain accessible on subdomain its not configured for

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have my staging config setup like so:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name staging.domain.com;
root    /var/www/staging/public;
```

and my production config setup like this:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name www.domain.com;
root    /var/www/production/public;
```

With no other redirects or anything.

The issue is that even if I disable the production config I can still access the staging server at www.domain.com.

Why is it not being restricted to its configured subdomain?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234600/nginx-subdomain-accessible-on-subdomain-its-not-configured-for

Comment: That IS this question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered a similar question like this before

Let me start with a small explanation on how nginx matches the hosts, quoting from [how nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

> In this configuration nginx tests only the request’s header field
>   “Host” to determine which server the request should be routed to. If
>   its value does not match any server name, or the request does not
>   contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to
>   the default server for this port.

When you disable the main server you only have 1 left, so nginx passes the request to it, if you want to avoid that you need to add a main server to block all unconfigured domains

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 403;
}
```

Then run

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

Then you're set

Comment: sorry i was using `return 304` while I meant return `403` please fix your config if u used `304`